# PHP Get a specific image path a <img> inside a url

Tags: php, html, dom

I am trying to get a specific image out of a url.
So for example if www.domain.com has a

`<img id="image100" src="images/dog.jpg">`

I am trying to get the path from that specific img tag.

I tried two different ways:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/<img id="image100" (.*?)src="(.*?)"\/>/i', file_get_contents($url), $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

error:
Notice: `Array to string conversion`

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$DOMxpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$image = $DOMxpath->query("//*[@class='image100]");
echo $image->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object
```

Comment: The `img` isn't self closing tag on the provided sample image so your regex shouldn't have it.

Comment: how should i fix it? i am not good with regex

Comment: I would make the self closing optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex should look something like this :

```
    /<img id="image100".*?src="(.*?)"/
```

A quick explanation of what is going on here:
.  matches a single character except for new line 
*? means repeat the previous token
() delimits a capture group, what you want to extract. 
/ escapes the character /
? makes the previous character optional

Basically, what this says is :  Look in the string for a substring that starts with

```
    <img id="image100"
```

contains any number of characters afterwards then continues with src="", then match whatever is between the "".

A great tool to test your regex is: https://regex101.com/r/eB8rU8/1

Answer (score 0):

Having that file_get_contents is like $img:

```
$img = '<img id="image100" src="images/dog.jpg">';

$resp = preg_match_all('/\<img\sid="image100"\ssrc="(.*?)"\/?\>/',$img,$result);

var_dump($result)

/* response:
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '<img id="image100" src="images/dog.jpg">' (length=40)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'images/dog.jpg' (length=14)
*/
```

Comment: preg_match_all('/\<img\sid="image100"\ssrc="(.*?)"\/?\>/', file_get_contents($url), $matches); I get array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: it has to find the <img> tag in the url provided

Comment: try this: `'/\<img\s{1,}id="image100"\s{1,}src="(.*?)"\/?\>/'`

Comment: still the same. The $img, has to be first found inside a url source code around all the other tags

Comment: the img have id or class?

Comment: it has both, id="image100" and class="img1"

Comment: echo $DOMxpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)"); seems to find some image, how can i tell it to specifically find the image with id image100 ?